# Looking for industry standard and/or tool to represent and export RDBMS metadata

Tags: export, metadata

Do you know of an industry standard that is designed to describe the metadata contents of a relational database (or part of it, such as tables, columns, etc.)?

Do you know if a tool exists that does export the metadata of any of the top 5 RDBMS tools in any format such as XML (without having to type in DDL in the syntax of particular database)?

Thank you.

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA is in the SQL standard http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Comment: @Phil, thanks for your input. If you care, you can make your comment an answer and I will up-vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several tools out there that can dump a database schema to XML.

You should be aware that "universal" tool might not catch all DBMS specific options (such as tablespaces, storage engines, special index types and so on).

The tools that come to mind are:

- [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) (a general XML based schema management tool, but it can "reverse engineer" an existing database) [Example XML](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/generating_changelogs)
- [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) ([Example XML](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/library.xml))
- SQL Workbench/J's [WbSchemaReport](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/wb-commands.html#command-schema-report)

All three are Java/JDBC based and thus work with a wide range of DBMS and operating systems.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This is very close to what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a set of views that are "common" across database vendors (Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...), there are the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views.

They are supposed to be a common standard across vendors (exactly how true I don't know). In SQL Server (versions >= 2000) you access them via [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].{view_name}, where {view_name} is any one of:

```
CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,
COLUMN_DOMAIN_USAGE,
COLUMN_PRIVILEGES,
COLUMNS,
CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE,
CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE,
DOMAIN_CONSTRAINTS,
DOMAINS,
KEY_COLUMN_USAGE,
PARAMETERS,
REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS,
ROUTINE_COLUMNS,
ROUTINES,
SCHEMATA,
TABLE_CONSTRAINTS,
TABLE_PRIVILEGES,
TABLES,
VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE,
VIEW_TABLE_USAGE,
VIEWS.
```

Here's some tips on how to make use of them: [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES | mssqltips.com](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/196/informationschematables/).

Comment: Oracle does not support information schema views.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I was looking for something more generic. Each vendor may have different format for reporting the results. I was looking for a generic format that would work across different vendors.

Comment: Yes, Oracle is a bit of the oddball for standards compliance in that respect. The following 2 URLs might help: http://etutorials.org/SQL/SQL+Bible+Oracle/Part+V+Implementing+Security+Using+System+Catalogs/Chapter+13+The+System+Catalog+and+INFORMATION_SCHEMA/Oracle+9i+Data+Dictionary/ (specifically Table 13-4) and http://www.alberton.info/oracle_meta_info.html#.URktN2eIp3A (try rolling your own). Also, the Wiki on RDBMS compliant with Information schema views: SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Emmad, to answer your question there are commercial tools available that use a standards based approach to extracting data from ALL databases out there and storing them in a generic for like XML. The collection of such tools is know as Metadata Management Tools. The one I have extensively worked with is Informatica Metadata Manager version 8.6 and up.

It will connect to all the industry leading databases and extract all the common, informational metadata for you and even profile the data to give you counts and data types. The data is stored in a standard know as the Common Warehouse Model (CWM). You have an interface to browse the objects and annotate any additional definitions you may want.

Since you mentioned avoiding to type DDLs I believe you do not want a solution for hardcore DBAs. I hope this takes you towards finding the solution you seek.

Comment: Are you selling that product?

Comment: Nope, :) you have to go to the company Informatica or try IBM if your organisation has a standing relationship with them. Personally this is what worked well for me, failing having to build my own solution... So I apologise if it comes across that I am "selling" that product :)

Comment: Just wanted to make sure. The answer does smell a little bit like it's spam. But if you are not related to the product it should be fine.